# Eliminar una parte de un string usando expresiones regulares en C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, scraping

estoy creando un proyecto en c# usando la libreria scrappy sharp para traerme los nombres de categorias o autos de una pagina para setups de simracing

ahora mismo estoy trabajando en llenar un combobox con los autos disponibles segun la categoria que uno elija en el combobox anterior

este es mi metodo

```
public void obtenerCoches(int posicion, int claseCantidad)
        {
            List<string> coches = new List<string>();
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("https://puredrivingschool.com/membersite/#gt-sprint-series");

            for (int i = posicion; i < claseCantidad; i++)
            {
                foreach (var nodo in doc.DocumentNode.CssSelect(".avia-image-overlay-wrap"))
                {
                    var nombreAuto = nodo.CssSelect("a").Single().Attributes["href"].Value;
                    coches.Add(nombreAuto);
                }
                //comentario
                cbCoche.Items.Add(coches[i]);
            }
        }
```

ahora en el medio (no se exactamente donde, tal vez donde marco un comentario lo que quiero es sacarle una parte a los strings de la lista coche, en el foreach obtengo 61 strings de los cuales selecciono solo algunos de acuerdo a los valores que paso como parametros en el for

Hola a todos, el atributo href vendria a ser algo asi "*https://puredrivingschool.com/membersite/gts-* ferrari-gt3 */*"

lo que está en cursiva incluyendo la barra del final es lo que quiero quitar y en general todos tienen el mismo patron solo cambiando lo que no esta en cursiva, se que puedo hacerlo con expresiones regulares, lo vi en javascript pero realmente no se como funciona exactamente en c#

una ayudita vendria muy bien xD

Comment: No veo tu expresión regular, ¿has intentado algo? Revisa esto: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: a ver intente solo una expresion que era algo como @"https://puredrivingschool.com/membersite \n"... y luego en la linea //comentario quise usar el metodo replace pero no se exactamente como usarlo, se que recibe dos parametros (el string viejo, el string nuevo)

tambien he intentado coches[i].substring(45) en la linea //comentario pero no parecia hacer nada

Comment: Prueba utilizar los metodos **string.Substring()** para coger el trozo que necesites y con los parametros de inicio y fin que puedes utilizar el metodo **string.IndexOf("caracter/es")** para que te devuelva las posiciones que necesites... Ejemplo: puedes usar el **IndexOf** para coger unicamente hasta **gts** coche[i].Substring(0,coche[i].IndexOf("gts"));

Comment: logre hacerlo de la siguiente manera, no es lo mejor pero funciona


coches[i] = coches[i].Remove(empieza,termina);
coches[i] = coches[i].Remove(coches[i].Count() - 1);